# How to play correct animation in unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I create animation in unity. The problem is that she plays 1 time.

```
void Update () {
...........
    if (Count > KnifeCount) {
        .........
        animator.SetBool ("Scale", true);
        InvokeRepeating ("DestroyClones", 0.5f, 0f);
    }
}

void DestroyClones() {
    int a = i + 1;
    allowTap = true;
    animator.SetBool ("Scale", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look the `IEnumerator` interface and the corresponding `StartCoroutine(IEnumerator enumerator)` method. Good place to start is [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the import settings of your animation (select animation in unity explorer) - check "loop Time".

If that doesn't help, check your Animator transitions. I guess you want to have parameter "Scale" as a transition condition.

You are using [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) which is fine, but you start this every `Update()` call, so you may want to [CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) to fix potential problems with that.

Comment: I turned off the loop time.
I have a parameter Scale.
CancelInvoke did not help.

Comment: what is `int a = i + 1;` supposed to do?

Comment: This is number of current level, then it change

Comment: Switching from InvokeRepeating to a Coroutine is a workaround, not a solution. You did not understand why your animation only ran once. If you are satisfied with that, it's okay. By the way `a` is a local variable, setting it to `i + 1` has no effect in the shown snippet.